# PHP - Formulário com validação de campos enviado repetidas vezes

Tags: php, post

Seguindo sugestão do moderador Sérgio, estou enviando uma nova pergunta, visto que a anterior foi sinalizada como duplicada e a única resposta recebida não resolveu o problema. Mas quero deixar claro que, todas as sugestões dadas em respostas às dúvidas (Formulário inserindo duas vezes no banco e Como evitar o envio de requisições PHP seguidas), foram testadas e não resolveram o meu problema.

As sugestões dadas não funcionaram porque o meu formulário faz validação de campos e com as implementações sugeridas, vários formas de desabilitar o botão Enviar, meu form parou de validar os campos.

Problema: eu tenho um formulário em PHP que envia por e-mail os dados fornecidos pelo usuário via método Post. Neste formulário eu faço a validação de alguns campos (CPF e alguns campos são obrigatórios). Quando o usuário clica em "Enviar" o processo às vezes é lento e, alguns usuários, clica várias vezes no "Enviar" causando o envio do mesmo formulário várias vezes.

```
<?php
require_once '_js/ValidaCPF.php';

$todos_campos_preenchidos = TRUE;
$msg_email_enviado = FALSE;
$ValidaCPF = TRUE;

if (isset ($_POST['salvar'])) {

$contato = $_POST['contato'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$cpf = $_POST['cpf'];

if(trim($_POST['contato']) == '') {
    $todos_campos_preenchidos = FALSE;
}elseif (trim($_POST['email']) == '') {
    $todos_campos_preenchidos = FALSE;
}elseif (trim($_POST['cpf']) == '') {
    $todos_campos_preenchidos = FALSE;
} 

$ValidaCPF = ValidaCPF($cpf);

If (($todos_campos_preenchidos) && ($ValidaCPF)) {

$para = "meuemail@meuemail.com";
$mailoculto = "outroemail@outroemail.com";

    //Codificações para envio do e-mail
    $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "Reply-To: $email". "\r\n";
$headers .= "Bcc: $mailoculto";

    //Assunto do e-mail
    $assunto = "Contato";

    //Corpo da mensagem
    $mensagem = "<table><tr><td width='180'><strong>Assunto:</strong></td><td>Envio de contato</td></tr>";
$mensagem .= "<tr><td><strong>Contato: </strong></td><td>".$contato."</td></tr>";
    $mensagem .= "<tr><td><strong>E-mail: </strong></td><td>".$email."</td></tr>";
    $mensagem .= "<tr><td><strong>CPF: </strong></td><td>".$cpf."</td></tr>";
    $mensagem .= "<tr><td valign='top'><strong>Data e hora: </strong></td><td>" . date('d/m/Y - H:i') . "</td></tr>";
    $mensagem .= "<tr><td valign='top'><strong>IP's: </strong></td><td>" . get_ips() . "</td></tr></table>";


    //Envio do e-mail
    If (mail($para, $assunto, $mensagem, $headers)){

        //Enviando e-mail de confirmação para o e-mail cadastrado
        $assunto = "Confirmação de Contato";
        $mensagem_confirmacao = "Prezado(a) " . trim($contato) . ", <br><br>";
        $mensagem_confirmacao .= "Você está recebendo este e-mail por ter solicita cadastro. <br><br>";
        $mensagem_confirmacao .= $mensagem;
        $headers_confirmacao  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
        $headers_confirmacao .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
        $headers_confirmacao .= "Reply-To: mail-noreply@meuemail.com". "\r\n";

        mail(trim($email), $assunto, $mensagem_confirmacao, $headers_confirmacao);            

        $contato = NULL;
        $email = NULL;
    $cpf = NULL;
        $msg_email_enviado = TRUE;
    }
}
```

}

Chamada do form:

```
<form method="POST" name="solicitacao" action="">

CPF do empregado:<sup>*</sup></font></td>
<td valign="top"><input type="text" name="cpf" class="mask-cpf" size="29"
<?php if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") { echo "value=\"" . $cpf . "\""; }?>></td>

<input type="submit" value="Enviar" name="salvar">
```

Answer (score 1):

Para quem quer manter a validação value do botão submit e está utilizando jquery há a seguinte solução.

```
var formEnviado = false;

$("#form").on("submit", function() {
    if(!formEnviado){
        formEnviado = true;
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

A forma mais simples, sem mexer muito no código seria só controlar se já foi ou não submetido...

```
$('input[type=submit]').on('click',function() {
    $(this).attr('disabled','disabled');
});
```

Fiz em jquery, mas podes transformar em javascript puro..

Comment: Fiz da seguinte forma e não funcionou, porque perdeu a validação.
    <input type="submit" value="Enviar" id="btnEnviar" onclick="javascript: this.form.submit(); document.getElementById(this.id).disabled = true;">